# How to properly set a selected item in a cshtml view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this `SelectList` defined in my ViewModel:

```
public SelectList AccomodationTypesTypes()
{
    return new SelectList(AccomodationTypes.Select(a => a.Type), "B"); 
}
```

`AccomodationTypes.Select(a => a.Type)` is an `IENumerable<string>` which currently consists of "A", "B", and "C".
According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist.-ctor you can provide a second parameter to indicate the selected value - hardcoded "B" in my case - but that does not work.

If it is any help, this is the snippet in the view that has the `SelectList`:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="Accomodation.AccomodationTypeId" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"><select asp-for="Accomodation.AccomodationTypeId" asp-items="Model.AccomodationTypesTypes()"></select></div>
</div>
```

The view displays characteristics of a particular selected Accomodation. AccomodationTypeId is a foreign key to the AccomodationType class, which denotes more general characteristics. In the view the user may select a different AccomodationType for the current Accomodation. When the view is rendered on screen I expect type "B" to be selected, which it currently is not. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You have a lot of bugs in this code, this is why  it is not working properly.

Comment: Hmm yes alot is up here. I think when using asp-for, you need to set `Accomodation.AccomodationTypeId` to whatever value "B" whould have in your select, but since you aint setting values for you select, this could be difficult. Could you try and add a picture of you rendered html (so not the cshtml code)?

Comment: @Serge No I disagree: I only had to change one line, see my answer. 
And further to my defense: the Microsoft article I mentioned states that "selectedValue" should be provided as the second parameter. "B" is perfectly ok as a value that can be selected.

Comment: @Cooz It will be working, but it is not the best way to do this.  I am sorry but I am wondering  since  you are answering your own questions, why  do you  post the questions?

Comment: @Serge Well I am certainly not the only one to do so - people answer their own questions all over Stack Overflow. Flash of insight maybe? Finally after searching for a day found an article that provided this insight? Valid reasons to me.
I'm a newbie and still learning - and, well, you obviously are way beyond that.
But then, what _is_ the best way to do this, and what is wrong with what I came up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out by using a different overload of SelectList:

```
public SelectList AccomodationTypesTypes()
{
     return new SelectList(AccomodationTypes, "Id", "Type");
}
```

`"Id"` binds with the *asp-for* (`Accomodation.AccomodationTypeId`) in the view, and the corresponding `"Type"` shows in the selection list. Does the trick.

I got off in the wrong direction because `return new SelectList(AccomodationTypes.Select(a => a.Type))` already gave me the dropdownlist I wanted, and according to the Microsoft article that I linked I only had to provide a second parameter to establish a selected value ("Id" probably, instead of "B" ).